# How to test if directory is writable in cross-platform .NET without actually writing anything?

Tags: .net

I know, I can just try to write a file, then fail if got a kind of access denied error. But I wonder if there is another way to just ask hosting OS can I write in specified directory. Of course I would prefer not to ask any OS directly, but using a cross-platform API.

Comment: I suspect the answer is No, and I also don't think it would be a good strategy to ask: the rights that you were just told you had could be taken away (say, by an admin) before you got a chance to use them.

Comment: DirectorySecurity for 4.8, FileSystemAclExtensions for net5 return information about ACL and probably have what you are looking for

Comment: ACL is Windows specific. I need to have Linux covered too. So I assume we just have to try write whatever is to write and return access denied if failed. I know, `try/catch` must be done anyway, I just wanted an early check, but then again, it's not important.